# Shell script filtering through jpg files attributes

Tags: shell, scripting, images, jpeg

I'm trying to find a way to filter through thousands of jpg files, and keep only the files with a certain attribute (such as the camera brand with which the picture was captured). How can I do so?

Comment: First you need a tool to read EXIF data from JPG files.  If you already have one, post it and try to figure out how to use it.  If not `exiftool` seems to be popular.

Answer (score 6):

There are several tools that can extract [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data or even manipulate image files based on their EXIF data.

With [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), you can rename files based on exif properties. In particular, you can easily dispatch files into subdirectories named after a particular exif property. You can then review the results and delete the directories containing files that you aren't interested in to your leisure.

```
exiftool  '-Directory<${Model}/%d' -r .
```

---

Exiftool makes this easy, but for illustration, here's a shell snippet that sorts jpeg files into subdirectories based on an EXIF property using [exif](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libexif). The property value must not contain `/` characters. You can find out the number for the `-t` option by running `exif -l`.

```
for f in *.jpg; do
  v=$(exif -m -t 0x0110 -- "$f" 2>/dev/null)
  if [ -n "$v" ]; then
    mkdir -p -- "$v"
    mv -- "$f" "$v"
  fi
done
```

With [Exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org), replace the `v=…` line by `v=$(exiv2 -g Exif.Image.Model -Pv -- "$f")`.

If your files are organized in a directory tree already, call `find` to traverse the directory tree recursively. Assume all your images are under a directory called `unknown`. The snippet below creates a directory for each image model and copies the files, mirroring the original directory hierarchy.

```
find unknown -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
    v=$(exif -m -t 0x0110 -- "$f" 2>/dev/null)
    [ -n "$v" ] || exit
    d=${0#*/}; d=${d%/*}
    mkdir -p -- "$v/$d"
    mv "$0" "$v/$d"
' {} \;
```